# My :hover transform scale and button are not working on part of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a [website](https://rhumbert1.github.io/devis-ms/) with pricing tables. These pricing tables have a button at the bottom and have a transform scale on hover, but they're not working as intended. The table at the bottom of the page works as intended but the ones above it do not. Does anyone have an explanation as to why this occurs?

Here is my CSS and HTML code for this part of the site :

```css
.first-titre-table {
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.titre-table {
  margin-top: 50%;
  color: black;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);

.snip1404 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  left: 20%;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 7%;
  display: block;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.snip1404 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.snip1404 .plan {
  margin: 6px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #730000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  background-color: #b30000;
}

.snip1404 .plan:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.snip1404 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.snip1404 header {
  background-color: #b30000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.snip1404 .plan-title {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.snip1404 .plan-title::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px 300px 0 0;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) transparent transparent;
}

.snip1404 .plan-cost {
  padding: 40px 20px 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.snip1404 .plan-price {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.snip1404 .plan-type {
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.snip1404 .plan-features {
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  text-align: center;
}

.snip1404 .plan-features li {
  padding: 8px 5%;
}

.snip1404 .plan-features i {
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.snip1404 .plan-select {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.snip1404 .plan-select a {
  background-color: #700000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.snip1404 .plan-select a:hover {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
}

.text-garantie {
  font-size: 17px;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #ddd;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .snip1404 .plan {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-title,
  .snip1404 .plan-select a {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-select,
  .snip1404 .plan-featured .plan-select {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-featured {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 440px) {
  .snip1404 .plan {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-non-featured {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-featured {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="snip1404">
  <h2 class="first-titre-table">
    Contrats Chaudière Gaz
  </h2>
  <div class="plan">
    <header>
      <h4 class="plan-title">
        Contrat 1 an
      </h4>
      <div class="plan-cost">
        <span class="plan-price">
          188€
        </span>
        <span class="plan-type">
          /an
        </span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <ul class="plan-features">
      <li>
        1 intervention/an
      </li>
      <li style="margin-bottom:63%;">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="plan-select">
      <a href="">
        Choisir
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the HTML, all the pricing tables have the same code. The only difference between them is the price showed and the number of lines in the "plan-features" list. I am also using some JavaScript code but I do not think it causes the problem. I could always post the script if needed.

Comment: I wondered the console of above link website where i can see the error of Jquery something like this $(".hover").mouseleave( it is showing error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main.js:1 it means that jquery script is not linked properly.Please try to resolve this error and it may start behaving normally thanks

Comment: because snip1404 has incorrect height give it like 700 that should fix it

Comment: Nope wasn't that, but Mihai T got me one step further of resolving my issue

Comment: Looks like it is an issue with the JS - if you take the last block out of the class (that block then breaks badly) but the next-to-last block now works

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. I added some more details to it. Let me know in the comments to that answer if it works for you or you need further assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `float:left` on `.plan` . Using `float` will get the element out of the normal flow of the document. That's why you should never use `float` for layout purposes. This causes the floated element to not be inside it's container so you cannot interact with it ( hover ) as you would like.

Use `flex` instead on the container `snip1404` . And `width:100%` on the title which i see has many 'names'. You should use a common class for all headings and give that class a `width:100%` . Then everything will go well.

Also the positioning with `position:absolute` on the content is not ideal. Other margins and etc look strange. But your problem is definitely caused by `float:left`.

Also, to position the button on the bottom, do not use `margin-bottom:63%` or something like that on a `li`. That almost never works on a responsive website. You have many options to make sure the button will always stay at the bottom.
You can also use `display:flex` together with `flex-direction: column` on the `plan` element. This is because we want to use flex styles on it's children and `column` because we want it's children to position one on top of the other not side by side. Then use `flex-grow:1` on the list ( features ) so it will grow and occupy in height the available space between the header and the button. So the button will always be at the very bottom of the `plan` element.

i made a simple example below

```css
.snip1404 {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .first-titre-table { /* here use a common class for all titles */
  width:100%;
 }
 .plan {
  background:red;
  /* use display:flex so we can use flex styles on the children */
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  /* no float left */
 }
 .plan-features {
 /* will occupy all the space available between the header and the button */
  flex-grow:1;
 }
 .plan:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
 }
```

```html
<div class="snip1404">
  <h2 class="first-titre-table">Contrats Chaudière Gaz</h2>
  <div class="plan">
    <header>
      <h4 class="plan-title">
        Contrat 1 an
      </h4>
      <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">188€</span><span class="plan-type">/an</span></div>
    </header>
    <ul class="plan-features">
      <li>1 intervention/an</li>
      <li style="margin-bottom:63%;"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Choisir</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="plan">
    <header>
      <h4 class="plan-title">
        Contrat 1 an
      </h4>
      <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">188€</span><span class="plan-type">/an</span></div>
    </header>
    <ul class="plan-features">
      <li>1 intervention/an</li>
      <li style="margin-bottom:63%;"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Choisir</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="plan">
    <header>
      <h4 class="plan-title">
        Contrat 1 an
      </h4>
      <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">188€</span><span class="plan-type">/an</span></div>
    </header>
    <ul class="plan-features">
      <li>1 intervention/an</li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Choisir</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that worked for me, i made the changes you suggested and it works just fine now, thanks ! Also I will update my website so you can see the changes.